# Does YouTube use method="GET" to submit the internal form for a video request?

Tags: php, youtube

The links in YouTube typically have the structure like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uvxslq63k0`. I'm guessing there's a PHP (or some other alternative to it) script running that uses the part after `watch?` to correctly select the video, and display it to the user. Does this method have a name (so that I can learn more about what's going on)?

My question is, upon clicking a link for a video, is there an internal form submission to a script to fetch the video content? I'm asking because HTML's value of form's method="get" delivers a similar url. Is that what's happening?

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
```

I want to build an ecommerce website that uses a similar way of fetching products page, with a `?categoryId=xxx` to fetch a page. How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: `https://www.youtube.com/v/5uvxslq63k0` ;9

Comment: Facebook also use this way to get user details on profile.php

Answer (score 1):

You will want to learn about [routing](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/).

With PHP, you need to look at the internal `$_GET` variables.

```
if (!empty($_GET['categoryId'])) {
    // get products in that category
    // render
}
```

Comment: So is this doable using a simple method="get" in the form submission page, and using php to deliver the page from the $_GET variable?

Comment: The `$_GET` variable is anything in the URL after the page: `index.php?variable1=hello&variable2=world` It is not tied to form submissions only.

Comment: Can you refer me a book which deals with this routing concept?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know of any books, $_GET and $_POST are core concepts with PHP and there are countless resources about these on the Internet.

Comment: If you look at the youtube link, it has something akin to `watch?v=5uvxslq63k0` instead of `watch.php?v=5uvxslq63k0`. How do they hide the file extension?

Comment: I'm not sure how YouTube do it however if you have Apache, you can use a thing called .htaccess files, search for "search engine friendly URLs"